# Upside-down Gaussian distribution

Tags: function, distribution, gaussian, normal-distribution

I'm looking for a function that is an upside-down function of Gaussian. So when x = 0, y should be 0. On both sides (positive and negative) the function should converge to 1. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a function, just subtract the Gaussian distribution function from 1.  You won't get a probability distribution function from that, of course; any such function must satisfy `$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx = 1$`.  (This is the wrong Stack Exchange site for typing mathematics in TeX.) The function you want won't be integrable.